# Teradata Query on Reading the contents from .csv file

Tags: database, teradata

I have a requirement where I have a csv file which contains only the date fields and I want to read a Teradata table on basis of the Date in my csv file. I tried to load the file to a table and read from there but I dont have access to create table in DB. Is there any other way I can achieve the task?

I am using SQL workbench.

Regards,
Saumya Ranjan

Comment: You probably got the rights to create a temporary table (when you logoff it's automatically dropped). `CREATE VOLATILE TABLE mytable(...) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;`